# Crash in android pollOnce

Tags: android

We are blocked because our Android service crashes in the native part, but we are unable to figure out what exactly is happening. Can someone shed some light on this?

```
 *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
 Build fingerprint: 'generic/sdk/generic:4.2.2/JB_MR1.1/576024:eng/test-keys'
 Revision: '0'
 pid: 3351, tid: 3351, name: UNKNOWN  >>> org.qeo.android.service <<<
 signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000001
     r0 ffffffff  r1 00000000  r2 00000000  r3 00000000
     r4 2a189fd0  r5 ffffffff  r6 00000001  r7 00000000
     r8 00000000  r9 00000014  sl 2a00bbb8  fp beec5694
     ip 00000000  sp beec5648  lr 400c0c3b  pc 400c0cfe  cpsr 60000030
     d0  3f8000003f800000  d1  003d09003fc00000
     d2  00000001000f4240  d3  bf62cda764a98eab
     d4  000f424000000000  d5  3ff0000000000000
     d6  4000000000000000  d7  3ff000003f800000
     d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
     d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
     d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
     d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
     scr 60000010

 backtrace:
     #00  pc 00014cfe  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollOnce(int, int*, int*, void**)+77)
     #01  pc 0005ed3f  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::NativeMessageQueue::pollOnce(_JNIEnv*, int)+22)
     #02  pc 0001e290  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
     #03  pc 0004d1f9  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+392)
     #04  pc 00038b45  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCheckCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+8)
     #05  pc 000276a0  /system/lib/libdvm.so
     #06  pc 0002b540  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
     #07  pc 0005fcab  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInvokeMethod(Object*, Method const*, ArrayObject*, ArrayObject*, ClassObject*, bool)+374)
     #08  pc 000674c1  /system/lib/libdvm.so
     #09  pc 000276a0  /system/lib/libdvm.so
     #10  pc 0002b540  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
     #11  pc 0005f9d5  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+272)
     #12  pc 0004984b  /system/lib/libdvm.so
     #13  pc 0003ce9b  /system/lib/libdvm.so
     #14  pc 00046871  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
     #15  pc 00047533  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, char const*)+390)
     #16  pc 00000db7  /system/bin/app_process
     #17  pc 000126f7  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_init+38)
     #18  pc 00000ae8  /system/bin/app_process
```